# Determine if reinterpret_cast is safe at compile time

Tags: c++, memcpy, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

According to the [`reinterpret_cast` page on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), there are 11 conversions that

> can be done with `reinterpret_cast`, except when such conversions would
> cast away *constness* or *volatility*.

So, my question is: is it possible to write a constexpr function like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool is_reinterpret_cast_safe() {
    // ...
}
```

that checks whether the conversion if allowed or not, based on those 11 points? Since compilers like GCC and Clang are able to check if the code breaks the strict aliasing rule, compiling with `-fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing`, I think is should be possible somehow.

I know C++20 introduces [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), but it is still not supported by any compiler. It could be useful to select between two casting functions at compile time

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 f_reinterpret_cast(T2 d) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2));
    return *reinterpret_cast<T1*>(&d); // could be undefined behavior;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 f_memcpy(T2 d) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2));
    T1 n;
    std::memcpy(&n, &d, sizeof(T2)); // OK
    return n;
}
```

with SFINAE or `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 conv(T2 d) {
    if constexpr (is_reinterpret_cast_safe<T1, T2>())
        return conv_reinterpret_cast<T1, T2>(d);
    else
        return conv_memcpy<T1, T2>(d);
}
```

You may find the code on https://godbolt.org/z/Ex6GnP.

Comment: So did you start writing it? Are you stuck? Cppreference nicely lists all cases, so at least some points are easy, like for point 1 pseudocode:`if ((std::is_integral<T1> || std::is_enum<T1> || std::is_pointer<T1> || std::is_member_object_pointer<T1>) && std::is_same<T1, T2>) return true;`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `std::memcpy`?

Comment: @Acorn mostly curiosity

Answer (score 1):

Compilers check the validity of a *reinterpret_cast expression* at compile time: aliasing rule violation happens when an object is accessed:

```
int i = 0;                                   //OK
double j* = reinterpret_cast <double*> (i);  //OK
double k = *j;                               //strict aliasing violation
```

It is not possible to check that a `reinterpret_cast` will not result in a pointer that can not be used to access the object it points to.